# change type of List<String>

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to insert the values of the products which are of type arrayList into the database but I'm getting this error `"java.lang.String cannot be cast to model.Product"`. The problem is with the cast I did in servlet. this is its code:

```
String buyer = request.getParameter("buyer");
List<String> prodlist = Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("product"));

List<Product> prodmlist = (List<Product>) (List<?>) prodlist;
Bill bill = new Bill(buyer, prodmlist);
myDAO.add(bill);
```

and this is the method which will be populated

```
public static void add(Bill bill) {
Connection cnx;
    try {
    cnx = Connect.getConnection();
    String req = "insert into bil values (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req);
    st.setString(1, bill.getBuyer());
    for (Product prod : bill.getProduct()) {
        st.setString(2, prod.getName());
        st.addBatch(); // add the statement to the batch
    }
    st.executeUpdate();    
    cnx.commit();
}
```

Comment: on which line of code are you getting the error?

Comment: @isaace third one, in the servlet. It can't admit the cast

Comment: That's not how objects work. If you want to make a list of `Product`s from a list of `String`s, you have to iterate over every string via a loop/stream and create/get the product object that corresponds to that string.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart oh I see, can u write the code please !

Comment: can we see your `Product` class?

Comment: of course @BenjaminUrquhart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
List<String> prodlist = Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("product"));
// Need to convert here...
List<Product> prodmlist = (List<Product>) (List<?>) prodlist;
```

You need to explicitly convert from `List<String>` to `List<Product>`. Do something along the lines of:

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
for (String s: prodList){
    Product p = new Product();
    p.setName(s);
    products.add(p);
}
```

Now, I am making the assumption you have a setter to set the name on Product. It may be you have a constructor you can pass the name to (and save a line of code).

Comment: there no longer the error but when I check the DB show nothing means the insertion do not works

Answer (score -1):

You cannot cast the list from a type to another one. If you want to "change the type" you must convert it :

using Java 8 lambda:

```
listReceived.forEach(string -> listProduct.add(new Product(string)));
```

usual way:

```
for (String string : listReceived) {
        listProduct.add(new Product(string));
}
```

I'm supposing that your class Product have a constructor that accept a string. If not, you should parse the string and fulfill each member of your Product in the loop.

```
// expecting that all information are separated by a space
Product product = new Product();
String[] splittedString = string.split(" ");
product.name = splittedString[0];
....
listProduct.add(product);
```